# Generate and scan QR code for payment purpose in same mobile in android app

Tags: java, android

We are creating an Android application where we will generate QR Code based on the upi id, now we are not able to scan that QR code which is generated within our application. As we are avoiding to use another mobile to scan the QR Code. Please let us know how to scan that generated QR Code in same mobile in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Use the API described here [Barcode API](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview)